# How to get a detailed results output from ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

When I do a query like this:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/xenforo/_search?q=message:test'
```

I get the following result:

```
{
    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 12.816886,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "xenforo",
                "_type": "post",
                "_id": "1778114",
                "_score": 12.816886
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The important _id is shown, but how would I get more information like the date, user and node information.

Here is some of my mapping information, I think the important part is shown:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/xenforo/_mapping?pretty=true'
{
  "xenforo113" : {
    "post" : {
      "_source" : {
        "enabled" : false
      },
      "properties" : {
        "date" : {
          "type" : "long",
          "store" : "yes"
        },
        "discussion_id" : {
          "type" : "long",
          "store" : "yes"
        },
        "message" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "node" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "thread" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "user" : {
          "type" : "long",
          "store" : "yes"
        }
      }
    },
```

I assume I will need to do a DSL query but I don't know which command would show the other information I'm after in the results.

Comment: Why did you disable _source field if you need it?

Comment: Hi dadoonet, all the documents I've seen have never shown how to include the _source field. Would you be so kind as to provide an example of it's use, or provide a link. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As you have disabled _source, you have to ask for explicit fields:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/xenforo/_search -d '{
    "fields" : ["user", "date", "node"],
    "query" : {
        "match" : { "message" : "test" }
    }
}'
```

See [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/fields/).

Comment: That works perfect. Thank you so much for your example, I'm in debt to you.

Comment: @AndyBajka just accepts dadoonet's answer and your debt will be considered paid in full ;) And if you want to enable _source, just set `"_source" : { "enabled" : true}` instead of `false`